# Howto draw keyboard input as fancy as broswers with <kbd> can?

Tags: java, swing

I want to show arbitrary shortcuts as fancy as stack* can, i.e. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974)). How can I do this best with java in swing?

Comment: Either with images, customized JLabels, or custom rendering. Which approach you take depends entirely on the context of your application. What have you tried?

Comment: I thought somebody must have solved this problem better than I would do from scratch. Can't believe there is no library for something like that. The biggest problem is the big number of possible shortcuts, especially with non simple char representations, e.g. `Print`, ...

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to set up a custom component that renders some text in the format you're describing. Again, how you do that depends entirely on your application, which is why there probably isn't a library that does something like this for you. What kind of component is the text you want to format in?

Comment: At least in web, you make a background image, and then use the normal character in front of it so it appear to be a key. Maybe you can use something like that, but as @kevin workman said, it depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a real fancy solution, but at least the users Local is taken into account by this Menu rendering logic of Substance:

```
    // get Accelerator text
    // KeyStroke accelerator
    String acceleratorText = "";
    if (accelerator != null) {
        int modifiers = accelerator.getModifiers();
        if (modifiers > 0) {
            acceleratorText = KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(modifiers);
            acceleratorText += UIManager.getString("MenuItem.acceleratorDelimiter");
        }

        int keyCode = accelerator.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode != 0) {
            acceleratorText += KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
        } else {
            acceleratorText += accelerator.getKeyChar();
        }
    }
    return acceleratorText;
```

Now I only need a fancy key looking box...